# Как при прохождении строки, игнорировать запятые?

Tags: c#, wpf, строки

Имеется строка кода, которая проходит по строке до символа, и записывает число в переменную.
Как сделать так, чтоб при прохождении строки, он записывал и запятую?

```
var last = String.Concat(TextLabel.Text.Reverse().TakeWhile((it) => Char.IsDigit(it)).Reverse());
```

Данная часть кода делает:
TextLabel.Text = 2+3,65;
last = 65;

Нужно:
TextLabel.Text = 2+3,65;
last = 3,65;

Comment: `Char.IsDigit(it) || it == ','`

Comment: Почему не `TextLabel.Text.Split('+')[^1]`?

Comment: Спасибо большое